# Read the chip info from a built-in NFC chip in mobile phone

Tags: samsung, nfc

As I know, there is a built-in NFC chip at the back of a mobile phone such as Samsung. So I would like to read the built-in chip info from that mobile phone.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you think that your device has a NFC-Tag?
Devices have normally a NFC-Reader with which you can read/write NFC-Tags

Comment: After googling, I found that Android bean use NFC chip to transfer data.  And S Bean use wifi-direct. Is that right?

Comment: You mean Android Beam and S Beam. Yes S Beam uses wifi-direct and Android Beam uses NFC.

Comment: So is there any chip on the back of phone to use Android bean feature?

Comment: No there is no chip but the android Beam feature writes the information 'to the air' and the other device reads it.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/108776/does-nfc-enabled-phone-means-the-phone-has-an-nfc-tag-inside?rq=1 This answer said there is built-in chip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37706/discussion-between-microgamer-and-user1156041).

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? There's no "fixed data" to read like with an NFC tag, the phone just transmits the data from some running app.

Comment: As I thought before, if there is built-in chip in phone, I don't need the extra NFC tag and I can also use this built-in chip as a identifer for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an NFC Tag (as the hardware device) but there is a chip which can act like an NFC Tag and provide data.

Comment: I found the one of nfc modes: NFC card mode in phone. It is used as a identifier for phone.