# Is it possible to add the NFC to the phone which does not have it?

Tags: nfc

My phone is a Motorola Moto 2g LTE (xt1072). It is really good phone but there is a one problem, it does not have NFC. Is there any solution, to add NFC to the phone which does not have it – and would Android be able to use it then? If yes to both, could you provide some links to such *existing* "equipment" as proof that it's not only "a nice theory"?

Comment: [NFC SD and SIM Cards](http://nearfieldcommunication.org/sd-sim-cards.html) seem to be an option, but I don't know much about them

Comment: @beeshyams I searched through the net but I did not find any market in which the NFC SD card is sell. Could you provide me with a link?

Comment: Checking the link @beeshyams gave, that [text exists at least since 6/2012](http://web.archive.org/web/20120614070720/http://www.nearfieldcommunication.org/sd-sim-cards.html) – yet I couldn't find any such SD or SIM card up to today (ie. more than 4 years later). Looks like [there were some start-up productions back in 2010/11](https://www.engadget.com/2011/06/01/netcom-shows-off-microsd-card-with-integrated-nfc-goodness-vide/), though – well, they've produced microSDs with NFC. But the article doesn't state if and where those were/are sold. At least Amazon doesn't have any.

Comment: related: Does NFC enabled phone means the phone has an NFC tag inside?https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/108776/does-nfc-enabled-phone-means-the-phone-has-an-nfc-tag-inside?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to say this, but it seems to be a long way off before truly turning a NON NFC into NFC phone (as pointed out by [Izzy in comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/152728/is-it-possible-to-add-the-nfc-to-the-phone-which-does-not-have-it/152738#comment195524_152728), there have been some efforts but no progress)

- [NFC SD and SIM Cards](http://nearfieldcommunication.org/sd-sim-cards.html) claims that *Both SIM and SD cards can be equipped with NFC chips* can be used to enable.
- Toshiba has come up with [NFC SD card](http://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/reviews/sd-cards/toshiba-nfc-card-16gb-card/) last year, but the catch is that it requires NFC enabled device to work with. All it does , is enabling seeing the contents of SD card without *physical connection*
- [NFC-enabled SIM cards](http://news.asiaone.com/news/singapore/new-nfc-enabled-sim-cards-may-not-take-now-dbs-research) launched a couple of months back in Singapore for paying for rail travel- but they work *only with NFC enabled* phones

Comment: Could you provide me with a link to such a NFC SD card?

Comment: click on the link above ! it shows Amazon prices too

Comment: I want to enable NFC with SD card. Not to have SD card which I can enable with NFC

Comment: that is not possible as I said in the first line of the answer

Comment: Turning Non NFC phones into NFC by using SD cards/ SIM is not a reality- so there os no way you can turn your device into NFC

Comment: What means "it requires NFC enabled device to work with"? (Why would a device that doesn't have NFC be "NFC enabled"?)

Comment: @JinSnow Only to emphasize that you can't use them on phones that don't have NFC