# What is the catch with microSD cards that have NFC support and will my Xiaomi Mi A1 support it?

Tags: external-sd, xiaomi, nfc, 8.0-oreo, mi-a1

I recently bought myself a Xiaomi Mi A1. Because it has a microSD card slot I'd like to buy a card. I noticed that some have NFC. Is it worth It? Is this real NFC or just a gimmick feature to buy such cards?

Will my A1 with Oreo recognize it and enable it or do I have to use apps to get this working, if this purchase would make a sense? 
[An example of the card.](http://www.toshiba-memory.com/cms/en/products/wireless-sd-cards/nfc/nfc-wireless-sd-card.html)

Comment: The card you linked is an SD card, not a micro-SD card. You can't use a normal SD card in your phone.

Comment: My mistake, sorry-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi A1 does not have NFC support. See specs [here](https://m.91mobiles.com/new/prod_specifications.php?id=31303) so it **doesn't make a difference** what card you buy. How you plan to use the card (external storage or [adoptable-storage](/questions/tagged/adoptable-storage) ), what you plan to store on it are important factors in deciding which card to buy. See  second question linked below for help

I am using a Samsung card and it is recognised. You don't need to use an external app

Related

1. [Is it possible to add the NFC to the phone which does not have it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/152728/131553)
2. [What is the minimum MicroSD speed necessary to extend the storage of an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/170347/131553)